# Как в rxJava получить объекты класса по отдельности

Tags: android, rxjava, mvp, rxandroid

Начал потихоньку, изучать rxJava.

Есть класс Page

```
public class Page {
    public String value1;
    public String value2;
...
    public Page(String value1, String value2) {
        this.value1= value1;
        this.value2= value2;
...

    }
}
```

Потом Retrofit

```
public static Retrofit getRetrofit(){

    if(retrofit==null){
        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = builder.build();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://www...")
                .addConverterFactory(PageAdapter.FACTORY)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();

    }

    return retrofit;
```

Интерфейс

```
public interface Service {
    @GET("myurl")
    Observable<Page> getData();
}
```

Теперь,суть вопроса. Как получить value1,value2....? Использую паттерн mvp.

Пытался так ( class MainPresenter )

```
(Observable<Page>) NetworkClient.getRetrofit().create(Service.class)
                    .getData()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe();
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: .subscribe( page -> println(page.value1) );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы получить элементы из потока, необходимо в метод `subscribe()` передать в параметры подписчика, в котором по крайней мере реализован метод `onNext`. В вашем случае вы вызываете метод `subscribe()` без подписчика и методы `onNext` и `onComplete` игнорируются. В комментарии @ЮрийСПб указал вам вызов `subscribe(Consumer<? super T> onNext)`, то есть в данном случае подписчик реализовывает метод `subscribe()` и подписчик обеспечивает callback для обработки элементов, испускаемых потоком.